# Determine the value of $x$ that is for $x^3-6x+7=0$ is false such that $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logic

> Determine the values of $x$ such that the following equation $x^3-6x+7=0$ is false, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$

My thoughts:

I think that I should solve the equation $x^3-6x+7=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. After that, the value of $x$ for which the property is false is $\mathbb{R}$ minus the solution of the above equation, but the problem is that I can't solve it.

Comment: What is your reason behind tagging calculus and pre-calculus together?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. "Determine the value of $x$ [...] for all $x \in \Bbb R$".

Comment: @pjs36 i agree. At most $3$ $x$ values exists for which the polynomial equals $0$

Comment: "Find value of $x$": Take $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-6x%2B7%3D0), we get $2$ complex roots and $1$ real root for the polynomial. We only care about the real root, which is:

$$x = -2\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{7-\sqrt{17}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}}$$

This is the only real value of $x$ that makes the polynomial $0$, so $x$ can take on any real value expect for the real root. Therefore, our answer is:

$$x\in\mathbb{R},\ x \ne -2\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{7-\sqrt{17}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}}$$

Comment: i know but how we can find step by step $$x = -2\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{7-\sqrt{17}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}}$$

Comment: @Educ did you take a look at the link provided by the other answer? That should help you.

Comment: @Educ, yes, if you realised, there are links embedded in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram gives us one real and two complex solutions.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-6x%2B7%3D0)
To find the exact value of the real solution, we can use the [cubic equation](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/).
If we let $x_1$ be the real solution, then the answer to your question is given by $\mathbb{R}\setminus x_1$.